# Priorities of piano scale practice as a complete beginner and what should I be paying attention to

Tags: piano, practice, scales

So, I decided my life needed a little more piano so I picked up a MIDI keyboard and started learning some of the basics. The very first thing I'm doing is learning the scales (starting with major) and chords (starting with no inversion).

I have some background in guitar and know that there are many things that one should be paying attention to while practicing scales, like finger tension, fingering, finger position within the fret, relaxing fingers not being used in a notes and their position, etc.

In piano, for now I'm strongly prioritizing getting the pattern in my head and muscle memory, but as I practice I notice there are some things I might be correcting, but don't know if now is the correct time to do it, as thinking about it often distracts me and gets me to fail the scale in some way. Things like the pinky fingers extending and being tense, note intensity, curvature of the hand, position of fingers not being used, and other things I'm surely missing.

I'm worried about making some negative patterns stronger with every practice, but don't know if now that I've just started (2 weeks) is the correct time to worry about it.

**As a complete beginner, what are my priorities when practicing scales? What should I be paying attention to? As I progressively improve, what things should I be adding to the "pay attention and correct" list? In which order?**

Getting a teacher is out of the question, it's impossible for me at the moment. I know "get a teacher" is a good advice, but it is sadly one I can't follow. Instead of asking this to a teacher, I'm asking this to you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a complete beginner, I would recommend that you take at least a couple of lessons from a good teacher.  I self-taught on guitar and bass but I had bad technique and ended up injuring my hands as a result, something that never happened to me when I learned piano from a teacher.

If you can't get a teacher then here's a site that may help you avoid some of the problems that students run into: http://www.pianofundamentals.com

For myself, I found that the best way to play and stay engaged was to make all of my scale exercises into melodies and all my chord exercises into chord progressions for songs.

To play while working on technique:

- Play as slowly as it takes to play perfectly with full attention on your technique and the notes. If you keep making mistakes play even slower.  Use a metronome and only increase the tempo when you can play perfectly.  This will save time, believe me.
- "Mend the fractures".  When you break a bone, the healed fracture will be stronger than the surrounding bone.  The same is true for your mistakes. When you make a mistake, repeat the passage again and again and again until you can play it perfectly before moving on.
- Concentrating on everything at once is very stressful for a beginner.  Each time through the exercise concentrate on one thing but each time through concentrate on a different thing.  Then start combining things.  For example, "This time I'm going to make sure that my fingers are perfectly placed.  This time I'm going to concentrate on the softest I can play a note.  This time I'm going to concentrate on my posture."  When each thing is good, then practice combining them.
- If you don't have a teacher, put your smartphone on a tripod and record yourself playing. First hands, then overall posture. Review the video and look for ergonomic problems. As a rule of thumb, you want to see everything in straight lines and right angles, especially fingers, arms, and spine.

Good luck!

Comment: "As a complete beginner, I would recommend that you take at least a couple of lessons from a good teacher." Getting a teacher is out of the question. It's not possible for me right now. For at least a year I will be doing this on my own and I don't have a choice about it. That's why I need to know this, I'm asking you guys instead of a teacher. :)

Comment: " I self-taught on guitar and bass but I had bad technique and ended up injuring my hands as a result, something that never happened to me when I learned piano from a teacher." It would be very useful to know which things to do to avoid injuries, then! It would be awesome if someone could include advice about how to avoid injuries in piano practice in an answer to this question.

Comment: I've addressed your comments in my answer.

Comment: +1 for mentioning getting a teacher regardless of what OP said about it. I injured myself too because I hadn't one. Now that I take lessons I realize that my teacher sees things I don't even feel in terms of tension and hand posture. There's no way I would be able to do this by myself. Why don't you take this year to do some intense ear training or sight reading, OP?

Comment: I agree. The issue I had with the original answer is that the only think on it was "get a teacher". Every question here and other SE could be answered like that. How do I do X thing? A: get a teacher. The job of the SE is to act like the teacher, so the "get a teacher" answers in SE sites tend to grind my gears. Here I see how it's important to mention the usefulness of a teacher, but I think there is also so much more to say about the subject than just "get a teacher". Ok, I got someone that will prevent my injuries, it's important, now answer the actual question. That's how I see it.

Comment: @user10960 In other words, I'm assuming there is more into piano scale practice than just preventing injuries. What's beyond that?

Comment: @user10960 " Why don't you take this year to do some intense ear training or sight reading, OP?" You are completely missing the point. This site IS the teacher. If I can have one in a year is irrelevant to other users that might be searching for similar advice. What's so hard to understand about it? Example answer: first avoid this and that to prevent injuries (it shouldn't be 100% of the answer, in my opinion), then the first week focus on x and y, when you can do r now focus on a and b, when you can p do m and n. Avoid h, f, and s. The things, you know, the teacher would tell you or me.

Comment: @JCPedroza - the big difference between this site and a teacher you may be with is that the teacher is actually watching your movements and correcting them there and then, with information gleaned from seeing what you are doing. That is just not possible here. You say you have a MIDI keyboard. If that doesn't have a weighted action like a reasonable piano, that's going to be your first solution - change it . If it has the correct action, well done.Most of what one learns when playing, as in how one gets the sound from a piano won't happen with an 'organ' feel.

Comment: @Tim I never said that there is no difference between having an actual teacher and this site. It's obvious is not the same. Those differences shouldn't stop pianist or pianist trainers to share their experience, what they do, what they teach other people to do, what are some common mistakes. You can't see my technique, but you can tell what is the goal, what is the target. That is more than possible here. I just asked for an overview of the priorities of the piano scale practice, something countless text provide, but for some reason some of you get stuck in the "get a teacher" stage.

Comment: @JCPedroza - "This site IS the teacher".

Comment: @JCPedroza I'm not going to get into this debate because you don't look like you're willing to change your mind. The only thing I was trying to do is help. I've been a piano autodidact and it sucked even though I more or less played another instrument. All I'm saying is that unless you're some kind of Erroll Garner it will suck for you too. Of course the choice to continue nevertheless is up to you.

Comment: @Tim Use the context of both the conversation and the question. I didn't mean to say that this site is the same as a human teacher, that doesn't make sense. What I mean is that this specific answer can be given by both a teacher and this site; this specific information can be given by both. In this case, the site can be the teacher. That doesn't mean that this site and a human teacher are exactly the same thing. That doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @user10960 I'm not trying to debate, I'm just trying to get an actual answer to the question, to which "get a teacher" is welcome, but it really doesn't answer the question, at all. The only thing the pre-edit answer contained was "get a teacher", which I find so frustrating since it's a common thing that happens around here. I don't need to change my mind, I agree with you. I should get a teacher, it is a good advice. *But*: 1) That doesn't answer the question 2) I can't get a teacher.

Comment: @Tim Think about it this way: all I asked for is priorities of scale practice. Can that question really only be answered by a teacher on a personal class? Of course not! There are countless text about the subject. The question can be answered, in general, without knowing the specifics of the student's technique. Of course more intimacy is needed for more detailed and personalized advice, but saying that you need a personal trainer to give an advice and overview of the subject is crazy talk to me.

Comment: Every time someone asks a (generally considered) basic instrument technique question here, it's inevitably answered with "get a teacher". But clearly they won't be asking the question on the site if they could do that! They would get a teacher and ask teacher that question!

Comment: "I self-taught on guitar and bass but I had bad technique and ended up injuring my hands as a result, something that never happened to me when I learned piano from a teacher." That could be partially because you're lucky with the piano and not so much with guitar and bass. Many professional pianists (and more generally, instrumentalists) who are conservatory trained have suffered injuries from playing.

Answer (score 2):

To make a good start, correctly, one should have an instrument that emulates a proper piano - touch sensitive, with a balanced action. A lot of keyboards, whilst looking like pianos, with the black and white bits, will play nothing like them The response is just very different. So, if one wants to get it right, that's paramount.

Scales (and chords and arpeggios) are the standard starting point, so one may as well use them. Playing positions for hands will vary as much as people do: one will play with fingertips pushing down the keys, another one will use pads. Watch good players - both methods can be made to work. I prefer knuckles up, bent fingers, but I've only played for 50 years so far, still might find a better way.At least, with scales, or running passages, with wrists and knuckles high, the thumb can pass under the hand ready for the next position.

Vary the way they are played - legato, staccato, piano, forte,slowly, fast, with combinations of these one will have a plethora of different modes of playing.

With arpeggios, use a couple of ideas - play only one octave up and down i.e. C-E-G-C-G-E-C. Play C-E-G-E-G-C-G-C-E-C up, then down - a broken chord. Play two octaves.

When one is good at, in particular, Cmaj, Emaj and Eb maj , use the same start note, play contrary. Same swap over points and fingering will make those easy and fun.

Since the OP quoted scales and chords this is as far as the answer goes now.

Comment: Are there other advantages in weighted keys, other than "feeling more like a real piano"?

Comment: It's probably that there's more disadvantage in learning with 'organ' type keys, as they tend to be pretty well switches, rather than a progressive action as one gets with a weighted key.So the way they're played feels quite different. You want to get it right from the start, so use the right tool.

Comment: But why one is "right" and the other "wrong" if the only difference is the feel? Do "organ" type keys don't have velocity sensitivity?

Comment: Yes, they often do, but,in a different 'feel' way, rather like having a real teacher, you won't know the difference in feel until you try it for yourself. I can't explain in a way you would understand over this site.

Comment: I know the difference and the feel since I have access to a variety of weighted keyboards, non-weighted keyboards, and pianos. I'm not asking you to describe the difference, I'm asking you why that difference makes one "right" and the other "wrong". I can't see why a difference in feel makes something better or worse, seems to be a preference thing. Is there an objective advantage to weighted keys or is it just a preference of yours?

Comment: Better or worse don't come into it.It's obviously the preference of most piano players, over an organ feel, otherwise they'd be playing any old keyboard.Right or wrong don't come into it.You asked specifically about piano playing,then stated you had a MIDI keyboard. You wanted to make sure you started with a good technique, which won't manifest itself if you learn on a keyboard which maybe doesn't have that feel.You can't learn to ride a bike by practising on a tricycle.If all you want to do is find your way round a set of keys, anything will do.You specified piano,so my answer reflected this.

Comment: I'm not planning to acquire a real piano, so that advantage doesn't really apply to me. I can see why it's important for people that plan to translate their experience to a real piano, and there's a real and objective advantage in that scenario. Thanks for your comments and answer I really appreciate it and they help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I know people who managed to learn a lot by themselves, without a teacher and on a MIDI keyboard. So good luck :-)

(I will be using the piano numbering scheme for fingers, I think guitarists count them differently):

1. From the beginning aim for even loudness. 4th and 5th fingers will be a problem (to soft), 2th finger and thumb might tend to be too loud.
2. The second important thing is articulation - the control of the time between releasing one finger and hitting another. You will see that getting it right is quite easy for thumb and 2th finger, but 4th and 5th tend to slur together (5th will hit before )

To practice points 1 and 2 - record yourself playing and listen to the recordings. Since you will be using a MIDI keyboard, it might be a good idea to record MIDI recording in a DAW (like Cubase), then you can actually see the loudness, timing, overlaps etc. of your playing (in the piano roll editor).

3. You want to use the same part of each of your fingers to hit keys - in the beginning, learn to use the tip of each finger, just by the fingernail (in case of the thumb it will be a bit to the side). This will be simple for fingers 1-3, but 4th and 5th will tend to hit closer to the first joint. Fight this!

Answer (score 1):

There are many teachers in existence who lack skills a "good" teacher should have and I don't know any teachers who don't consider themselves "good". Therefore I take issue with a blanket response of get a good teacher. I feel there are other ways to learn besides formal instruction. Children become very proficient on their digital devices just by playing with them in an unorganized uninstructed manner. There are also many accomplished musicians who began with no formal training, but had access to an instrument they could tinker and play with. If the interest is there, formal training is only one of many ways to learn to play. Book study can give a lot of pointers, and so can experimentation, mistakes might be made in the process of learning, but that is just part of learning. There will always be the possibility of injury in anything you decide to do, but if you make a habit of being careful in your endeavors that possibility is greatly reduced. The same idea applies to learning an instrument. Just use common sense.
You didn't say if you were a sight reader or not, but it occurred to me that learning scales and chords and learning sight reading can pretty much go hand in hand and if you're interested in learning sight reading you can find workbooks that can get you  started. Just understand that there will be a lot of work involved if you don't enjoy what you are doing, but if you do enjoy it, it becomes play, so it makes good sense to do your learning in ways you can enjoy. I wish you the best of luck.